# How to dynamically change destination index in continuous Elasticsearch transforms?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to extract some high level metrics from the log data we store in Elasticsearch. To achieve this I am running a number of continuous transforms to generate more meaningful high level logs.

I have included a `dest` block in my transform definition JSON, as follows:

```
"dest": {
  "index": "transform_index" + date 
}
```

But the aforementioned code is evaluated only once on transform creation time, and is not updated in future **sync cycles**.

I am looking for a solution to change the transform index on a monthly basis and I think it is doable using a `pipeline`. However, I am not sure how.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've read through the documentation and found my answer. I've managed to achieve what I needed using pipelines, I've created a pipeline as follows:

```
PUT /_ingest/pipeline/add_timestamp_pipeline
      {
        "processors" : [
          {
            //copy timestamp field from transform source
            "set" : {
              "field" : "@timestamp",
              "value" : "{{@timestamp}}"
            }
          },
          {
            //create indices based on @timestamp rounded to month
            "date_index_name" => {
              "field" => "@timestamp",
              "index_name_prefix" => "hourly-activity-index-",
              "date_rounding" => "M",
              "date_formats" => ["UNIX_MS"]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

Then you use the created pipeline in your transform:

```
PUT /_transform/hourly_transform
{
  "dest" : {
          "index" : "hourly_activity_index",
          "pipeline" => "add_timestamp_pipeline"
           },
  //rest of the transform definition
}
```